# split an array in known fragment

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

I have an array of hashes that contain a boolean key, like

```
    [{"n"=>"img01", "h"=>1},
     {"n"=>"img02", "h"=>1},
     {"n"=>"img03", "h"=>0},
     {"n"=>"img04", "h"=>1}]
```

my goal is split the in groups that have one of these condition of h key:
  `[1,1,1]` or `[1,0]` or `[0,1]` or `[1,1]` or single value if any of these condition is not possible. In this example the only way to split the array is

```
     [{"n"=>"img01", "h"=>1},{"n"=>"img02", "h"=>1}]
```

and

```
     [{"n"=>"img03", "h"=>0},{"n"=>"img04", "h"=>1}]
```

but first it should search for an array done in this way

```
          [{"n"=>"img01", "h"=>1},
           {"n"=>"img02", "h"=>1},
           {"n"=>"img03", "h"=>1}]
```

and then looking for the other combinations

I've tried to splice the original array in groups of 3 (in test used just an array of 1 and 0)

```
 irb(main):030:0> b=a.each_slice(3).to_a => [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]
```

and then confront the result to the biggest array first [1,1,1], and then try to split again if not

```
 irb(main):055:0> (b[0] -  [1,1,1]).count => 1
```

so move to next sub array the last value

```
 irb(main):060:0> b[1].push(b[0].pop)=> [1, 1, 0, 1]
```

repeat the search in the first two-elements array

```
(irb(main):061:0> b[0] - [1,0]).count
(irb(main):061:0> b[0] - [1,1]).count
(irb(main):061:0> b[0] - [0,1]).count
```

and then merge the other sub-array, split it again and repeat the search, but it is definitely
 messed up

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. what is [1,1,1]? what does the array denote/

Comment: I've edited the question, hope is more clear. It is an array of pictures and I have to compose in certain groups, based if the groups contains horizontal or vertical pictures

Comment: What should be done with 3 consecutive zeros ?

Comment: it should be splitted in 3 different sub-array each one with just one hash

Comment: 1. Show us what have you tried. SO is not a service to request others to write the code for you for free. 2. If it is guaranteed there are 4 elements in the input, it’s easier to perform using a brute force.

Comment: Should the result be greedy? Does `0011` become `0` `0` `11` or `0` `01` `1`? Does `10` always have a higher priority than `01` or is it simply whichever pattern appears first?

Comment: Bigger array should be come first of shorter one, so 0 01 1 it is better than 0 0 11

Comment: You can select elements of Array using [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select), fairly simple. Try it and if you face an issue, then open a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `1` and `0` as sort of an imaginary image width. A horizontal image is assumed to be double the width of a vertical image.

You can then proceed to use that to calculate how wide the images on the current row of images is and will the next image still fit on that row.

When `width + next element width` is larger than what fits a "row of images", you start a new row.

Example:

```
input = [{"n"=>"img01", "h"=>1},
   {"n"=>"img02", "h"=>1},
   {"n"=>"img03", "h"=>0},
   {"n"=>"img04", "h"=>1}]

image_rows = []
current_row = []
current_width = 0.0
input.each.with_index(1) do |image_data, idx|

  image_width = image_data['h'] == 1 ? 0.5 : 1.0

  if current_width + image_width > 1.5
    image_rows << current_row
    current_row = [image_data]
    current_width = image_width
  else
    current_row << image_data
    current_width += image_width
  end

  if idx == input.size
    image_rows << current_row
  end
end

require 'json'
puts JSON.pretty_generate(image_rows)
```

Outputs:

```
[
  [
    {
      "n": "img01",
      "h": 1
    },
    {
      "n": "img02",
      "h": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "n": "img03",
      "h": 0
    },
    {
      "n": "img04",
      "h": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

- When current row has `111` the width is `0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 = 1.5` => nothing fits in
- When current row has `10` the width is `1.0 + 0.5 = 1.5` => nothing fits in
- When current row has `01` the width is `0.5 + 1.0 = 1.5` => nothing fits in
- When current row has `11` the width is `0.5 + 0.5 = 1.0` => only 0.5 fits in
- When current row has `1` the width is `0.5` => either 1.0 or 0.5 fits in
- When current row has `0` the width is `1.0` => only 0.5 fits in

You can find the first group containing `111` by doing `image_rows.find { |row| row.size == 3 }`.